# JQuery UI Drag/Drop and Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

I'm using JQuery UI draggable/Droppable and sortable operations.

I have two section top/bottom i'm dragging list records from bottom section to top section were in top section i'm performing sorting

All is working well at the moment but i found one issue in my sorting operation in top section when i sort list records

Let say i place record 3 and placed into record 1 in inspect element my dragged record 3 is duplicating its record(creating one copy of it) i want list record should not be duplicated/cloned while sorting Please somebody help me out in fixing this issue Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/BCnyU/204/

**List record duplicating snap shot**

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="drop_list">
        <ol id="sortable" style="list-style:decimal;">
            <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
            {
            ?>  
                <li id='arrayorder_<?php echo $i;?>' class="draggable_li qitem">
                    <div class="main_div">
                        <div class="secondary_div">
                            <label class="item_div">
                                <span class="item">Item = <?php echo $i; ?></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="sort_list">
    <ul id="draggable">
        <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
            {
            ?>  
                <li id='arrayorder_<?php echo $i;?>' class="draggable_li qitem">
                    <div class="main_div">
                        <div class="secondary_div">
                            <label class="item_div">
                                <span class="item">Item = <?php echo $i; ?></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sortable").sortable(
        {
            helper : 'clone',
        });

        $("ol li").disableSelection();

        $(".sort_list li").draggable(
        {
            tolerance:"pointer",
            helper : 'clone',
            refreshPositions: true ,
            revert : 'invalid',
            opacity:.4,
        });

        $(".drop_list ol").droppable(
        {
            revert:true,
            greedy: true,
            refreshPositions: true,
            drop : function(ev, ui) 
            {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
                if($(this)[0].id === "sortable")
                {
                    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' ).closest('li').prependTo(ui.draggable.closest('ul')); 
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you are doing a `clone` of the dropped element.
Instead of this:

`$(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);`

Do:

`$(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);`